# Songify the speech

Tags: vocals, autotune

I am trying to create a song like this video.

I use both ableton & FL studio. I don't really worry for the music part. But for the speech, how can I achieve it? 
I guess they use melodyne.

I try to do it in Melodyne too but the sustains of the voice is very short and it doesn't sound as they did.

is there a reference tutorial or step by step explaination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gregory Brothers use Antares' [Auto-Tune](http://www.antarestech.com/), which supports both pitch and time correction. In fact, for its earlier episodes, *Songify the News* was known as *Auto-Tune the News*.